# Loop up and down to print "-" and "*"

Tags: python

The first line of the pattern has 5 dashes followed by 1 star, the second line has 4 dashes followed by 3 stars, the third line has 3 dashes followed by 5 stars, etc.  The last line of the pattern has 0 dashes  and  11  stars.
I'm trying to print out the following result. I don't know any changes should be made to my code?

```
-----* 
----*** 
---***** 
--******* 
-********* 
***********

def printing(dash, star):
    for i in dash:
        print("-")
    for i in star:
        print("*")          
    print(dash, star)

def main():    
    dash = 5
    star = 1      
    while dash >=0:
        printing(dash, star)
        dash = dash-1
        star = star+2
main()
```

Comment: try to complete this basic assignment on your own :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What's wrong with your code

`for i in dash:` will try to iterate over every element `i` in the iterable `dash`. But you gave it an integer, which is not iterable.

For that to work as-is, you should do `for i in range(dash)`. `range(n)` returns a list of n integers starting with 0. That way you can iterate `dash`times.

### Easier approach

Given that python allows you to multiply strings by integers effectively repeating said strings, and chain them by simply adding them with `+`, you can have a much simpler approach:

```
def printing(dash, star):
    print '-'*dash + '*'*star
```

Comment: This is why I love this language.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in a new algorithm. Try this.

```
s="-----*"
print(s)
while "-" in s:
    s=s.replace("-*", "***")
    print(s)
```

You'll notice the `"-" in s` line. That's just checking to see if a hyphen is in the string. You can do that since strings act like iterators. You can add as many hyphens as you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `for i in xrange(dash)`. https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Answer (score 0):

You cant iterate through int, you need to use `range()`

Try this:

```
def printing(dash, star):
    for i in range(dash):
        print("-", end="")
    for i in range(star):
        print("*", end="")          
    print()

def main():    
    dash = 5
    star = 1      
    while dash >=0:
        printing(dash, star)
        dash = dash-1
        star = star+2
main()
```

output:

```
-----*
----***
---*****
--*******
-*********
***********
```

Comment: what does end="" mean? and why there is a print() in the end?

Comment: A simple `print()` creates a newline, which you don't want. Usually it would be possible to use `print(),` to avoid that. the `end=""`also does avoid the newline. After the row is done there should be the newline, this is why an empty`print()` comes around.

Answer (score 0):

As @wRAR mentioned, you should use `for i in xrange(dash)`.  Another thing is that, you should properly use print to control the newline, `\n`

In Python 3.X:

```
def printing(dash, star):
    for i in dash:
        print('-', end='')
    for i in star:
        print('*', end='') 
    print ('')
```

In Python 2.x:

```
def printing(dash, star):
    for i in dash:
        print '-',
    for i in star:
        print '*', 
    print ''
```

Comment: may I ask what does end='' and print('') do?

Comment: @dfefef https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print for the first part.  The second is just printing an empty string (to start a new line)

Comment: Ok. It's not `"`, it's two single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use Python's string repetition and concatenation operators to build your lines, rather than using loops to print each character separately. If you multiply a string by an integer, it will be repeated that number of times. Adding two strings concatenates them.

Here's a simple function that produces the output you want:

```
def main():
    for dashes in range(5, -1, -1):    # dashes counts down from 5 to zero
        stars = 1 + 2*(5 - dashes)     # the number of stars is derived from dashes
        print("-"*dashes + "*"*stars)  # just one call to print per line
```